# Ionic app, recurring monthly payment

Tags: javascript, software-development, mobile, ecommerce, angular

I am developing an Ionic 3 app. I would need to integrate recurring payments to my app... So as to get paid every month by the user, whith user's card data.

I tried Stripe, which seems to be the simplest option and I noticed native ionic plugin doesn't support recurring payment.

My question is... is there any way to integrate stripe.js in an ionic 3 project? Shall I use another option, instead of stripe, so as to succeed integrating recurring payments?

Every recommendation provided will be kindly taken into consideration. Thanks in advance!

---

[Update] OP said in comments

> Is there any plugin I can use? Is it possible to integrate paypal or stripe subscription plans in ionic?

Comment: Are you asking us to recommend some software? That's all we do on this site, and I don't really see that in your question

Comment: My apologises, I am only asking for an approach... Is there any plugin I can use? Is it possible to integrate paypal or stripe subscription plans in unity? Shall I go for cloud functions with firebase? All I want is an approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I edited your question to make it on topic and hope that you will get an answer. Welcome aboard :-)